# Raspberry Pi - how to use I2C and GPIO at the same time?

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, gpio, i2c, wiringpi

I'm working on a project where I need to use GPIO to toggle pins high and low as well as gather sensor data from an I2C peripheral. I have each component working separately, GPIO using wiringPi and I2C using open(...,...) and ioctl(...,...,...). Separately they work great. When I run them together, the I2C bus gets in a state where i2cdetect shows all possible address values, and I can't communicate with the I2C device again until I reboot. Has anyone seen this before or does anyone know what I can do to fix this?

Comment: I think this would be a great fit on the [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange site](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Just  moved there: : http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/53326/problem-using-i2c-with-ioctl-and-gpios-with-wiringpi-simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

I am working on project with gpio and i2c at same time and doing all with **wiringpi** lib in c/c++.
why and what is reason to use ioctl directly?
Is it separated modules you developing or it can be monolithic application?